# Swapping the "home" button functionality

Tags: 2.2-froyo, buttons

Currently (2.2) pressing the home button goes to the home app shortcuts, and long-prerssing it opens recently used tasks.

Is it possible to swap these actions? Then quick press would open recent tasks.

(I'm also interested in answers that require root, or a custom rom.)

Comment: What device is this?

Comment: @cjk Does the device matter? Samsung GT-S5570.

Comment: I would look for launcher replacements - I am not aware of any changing long press behavior, but many of them provide options to change the home button behavior.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the [AOKP ICS ROMs](http://aokp.co/index.php/releases), then there is a setting under `System Settings->ROM Control->General UI->Long Press Home Action` but it seems to only let you choose between different kinds of recent menu lists. I know this is a narrow part of your situation, but information for your taking nonetheless.

Comment: Good information, but as you said, only a narrow part of what I'm asking for. Thanks, though!

Comment: if I find anything else, you'll be the first to know!

Answer (score 1):

Another method exists, and like you indicated, it requires at the very least root access and possibly a custom ROM.

1. Hook your device up to a computer via **adb**.
2. Pull your **keypad.kl** file. For my HTC EVO 4G, it was
   `/system/usr/keylayout/supersonic-keypad.kl`, regardless of what it
   is called, you should find it somewhere close to
   `/system/usr/keylayout`
3. Open this file with a text editor, and edit as you please following
   the pattern of the file.

For me, the HOME button is `102`, so remapping this key to the camera would be `key 102     CAMERA       WAKE_DROPPED`.

A key marked `WAKE` will wake the device when it is pressed, `WAKE_DROPPED` can affect the system without waking the screen.

**NOTE:** this *may* only allow you to change the functionality to built-in options, but there are several functions available, including volume options, other softkeys, camera, power, any characters, or playback controls, such as `PLAYPAUSE`.

[This](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/keymaps_keyboard_input.html) is the Android source and includes example keymaps.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to assign the required functions to the button with ButtonRemapper: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=850464

Comment: From the FAQ in the first post: *"Q: can you do also other remappings with the buttons, like **for example long pressing,** double press, context sensitive remappings etc. A: For now, this is pretty much it."* So, unfortunately no.

Comment: Then I'm afraid the answer is: no, it's not possible to swap these actions.

Answer (score -1):

ClutchPad can be setup to do pretty much whatever you want.. check it out [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stevealbright.clutch&hl=en)

Comment: Nice idea to solve the underlying problem, thanks for the recommendation. However, from the description it doesn't seem touch the home button functionality at all, but instead replicates it by adding it's own "home button" to some corner of the screen. A constant visual element obstructing a part of the screen - even if a small part - is pretty much unacceptable for me.