# Mapping bluetooth mouse buttons

Tags: bluetooth

I have a bluetooth keyboard and mouse I use with my HTC EVO 4G, and I have tweaked my keyboard using the methods in the answers to questions like [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23847/changing-layout-of-physical-keyboard/23953#23953) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23519/swapping-the-home-button-functionality/23889#23889).

I would like to know if there is a way to do a similar thing with the buttons on my bluetooth mouse.

i.e. I would like to map the wheel click to turn off the screen, or make the right click emulate a long click rather than go back a view.

I am running Cyanogenmod 7.1 (stable) currently.